# Nodejs: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'connect'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to **login via facebook and I am using Node.js in server**. But when I am running in localhost I am getting **an error TypeError: Object # has no method 'connect'.**

**server.js**

```
// server.js

// set up ======================================================================
// get all the tools we need
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var neo4j = require('neo4j');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');

// configuration ===============================================================
neo4j.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database

require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

app.configure(function() {

    // set up our express application
    app.use(express.logger('dev')); // log every request to the console
    app.use(express.cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
    app.use(express.bodyParser()); // get information from html forms

    app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating

    // required for passport
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'heyhellopeoplediscoverapp' })); // session secret
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
    app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

});

// routes ======================================================================
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

// launch ======================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```

**Following is the error that i got from the console:**

```
neo4j.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database
      ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'connect'
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node\easy-node-authentication-facebook\server.js:1
5:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

**Thanks in advance!!!**

Comment: What's that to do with Facebook? It seems to be an issue with neo4j which seems not to have a _connect_ method. https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j

Comment: @pintxo: Thanks... Seeing to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info at npm, you need to create an instance of the database which would then have a connect method
var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase(configDB.url) ;
db.connect();

Comment: Actually it would seem there in no connect method, and once instanciated , the connection is made so strike db.connect() from my answer. For more info see https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j/blob/master/lib/GraphDatabase._coffee